# Как перевести фокус на найденное слово?

Tags: java, android, focus

Поиск подсвечивает слово в `TextView`, он находится в контейнере `ScrollView`.

Нужно, чтобы фокус переходил (автоматически прокручивался) на подсвеченное (найденное) слово, если оно вне зоны видимости экрана.

Подскажите, кто знает, может, есть ссылка на пример?

```
private void searchFor(String paramString)
{
    int i = 0;

    TextView localTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Spannable localSpannableString = new SpannableString(localTextView.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] arrayOfBackgroundColorSpan = (BackgroundColorSpan[])localSpannableString.getSpans(0, localSpannableString.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);
    int j = arrayOfBackgroundColorSpan.length;
    while (i < j)
    {

        localSpannableString.removeSpan(arrayOfBackgroundColorSpan[i]);
        i++;

    }
    for (int k = TextUtils.indexOf(localSpannableString, paramString); k >= 0; k = TextUtils.indexOf(localSpannableString, paramString, k + paramString.length())) {
        localSpannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FFEA00")), k, k + paramString.length(), 33);

    }
    localTextView.setText(localSpannableString);
   // search.setSelection(search.getText().length());

}
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView paramTextView, int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
{


    if ((paramKeyEvent == null) || (paramKeyEvent.getAction() == 1))
    {
        searchFor(this.search.getText().toString());
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(paramTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
    return true;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]